# javascript - Better Way to Escape Dollar Signs in the String Used By String.prototype.replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, escaping

I want to replace a string by another. I found when the replaceValue contains `"$"`, the replace will fail. So I am trying to escape `"$"` by `"$$"` first. The code is looks like this:

```
var str = ..., reg = ...;
function replaceString(replaceValue) {
  str.replace(reg, replaceValue.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$'));
}
```

But I think it is ugly since I need to write 4 dollar signs.

Is there any other charactors that I need to escape? And is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a way to call `replace` that allows us not to worry about escaping anything.

```
var str = ..., reg = ...;
function replaceString(replaceValue) {
  return str.replace(reg, function () { return replaceValue });
}
```

Comment: Specifically, the point is to wrap the replacement string in a function; that way no escaping is done to it.

Answer (score 11):

Your method to escape the replacement string is correct.

According to section 15.5.4.11 String.prototype.replace of [ECMAScript specification edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), all special replacement sequences begins with `$` (`$&`, `` $` ``, `$'`, `$n`, `$nn`) and `$$` specify a single `$` in the replacement.

Therefore, it is sufficient to escape all `$` with double `$$` like what you are doing right now if the replacement text is meant to be treated literally.

There is no other concise way to do the replacement as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, nothing you can do about it.
It's just how JavaScript works with regular expressions.

Here's a good article with the list of all replacement patterns you should be aware of:
http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.11

Comment: The article doesn't say anything about avoiding them. Rather, they are the syntax of the replacement string.

Comment: Correct. But see the OP's question: `Is there any other charactors that I need to escape?`. The article provides the patterns he should know about.

Comment: I think you should change the wording to: "... list of all replacement patterns, which your method has done a good job at escaping them"