# JavaScript string.replace using "$$" outputs "$"

Tags: javascript, string

Can anyone explain to me why JavaScript outputs a single `$` when using `$$` as the replace value?

```
"hi".replace("hi", "$$bye$$");
"hi".replace("hi", "\$\$bye\$\$");

//both output -> $bye$
//but I expected $$bye$$
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102491/javascript-better-way-to-escape-dollar-signs-in-the-string-used-by-string-prot. Also https://www.google.com/search?q=string+replace+dollar+sign+javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` acts as a metacharacter in the replacement strings for that function. The string `$$` is used to indicate that you just want a `$`. Otherwise, `$` followed by a digit refers to the contents of a *capturing group* from the regular expression. As an example:

```
alert("aaabbb".replace(/(a+)(b+)/, "$2$1")); // bbbaaa
```

The string "\$\$bye\$\$" is exactly the same as the string "$$bye$$". Because `$` is not a metacharacter in the *string* grammar, the backslash preceding it will be ignored.

You can double-up on the backslashes to have them survive the string constant parse, but the `.replace()` function will pay no particular attention do them, and you'll get `\$\$` in the result.