# How to replace multiple dollar ($) signs by pound signs in a Javascript MathJax text string?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

In the character sequence:- `$$ \sin \theta $$` I want to replace every `$` by a  `£`.

---

(EDIT: I have since learned that the following approach is overkill, please ignore it. I have added an answer that relates some key learning points.  But kudos to Mister Jojo for giving the answser to the original question).

---

I have looked at the answers to this question:- [better-way-to-escape-dollar-signs-in-the-string-used-by-string-prot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28102491/javascript-better-way-to-escape-dollar-signs-in-the-string-used-by-string-prot).

I have tried to apply the answer of Leonid:-

```
var str = ..., reg = ...;
function replaceString(replaceValue) {
  return str.replace(reg, function () { return replaceValue });
}
```

This is my interpretation:-

```
var str = "$$ \sin \theta $$";
//var reg = "/\$/g" ;// TIL: reg is a regular expression so doesn't need "".
var reg = /\$/g ; //... I tried varying the number of $ and/or backslashes,` without success so far.
var replaceValue = "£";
var output = replaceString( replaceValue ); 

//-----------------------------------------------

function replaceString( replaceValue ) 
{
  return str.replace ( reg, function () { return replaceValue });
}

//-----------------------------------------------

// desired output =  "££  \sin \theta ££"
// actual output  =  "$$  sin \theta $$".
```

It isn't working.

Comment: The function in passed to `str.replace` should just be the string itself, so: `str.replace(/\$/g, '£')` would work

Comment: `"/\$/g"` isn’t a regular expression, but a string; the literal character sequence `/$/g` appears nowhere in `str`, hence it isn’t replaced. `/\$/g` would target every single `$`. `/\${2}/g` would target pairs of `$`s. `/\${2,}/g` would target groups of at least two `$`s. Read the [documentation on `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @user4642212. Thanks for clarifying about regular expressions. I do wish to target every single `$`. I have skimmed through those recommended documents but still don't know how to avoid losing the backslash in `\sin`.

Comment: @Tom thanks for pointing out the format of the regex string.  But if I enter into the console: `rep = "$$ \sin \theta $$".replace(/\$/g, '£')` the answer I get is `"££ sin  heta ££"`.  But I think I understand things better now, as per my 'answer'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use [replaceAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replaceAll) method

```js
let s1 = "$$  \sin \theta $$"
  , s2 = s1.replaceAll('$','£')
  ;
console.log ( s2 )
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't really answer the problem with the question, which is that the OP is using a regex as a string instead of a regex.

Comment: @Samathingamajig don't you think it's misleading to imagine the need for a useless (and badly written) regex? and that he wants to use a simple replace instead of a replaceAll? what is the point of looking for complications?

Comment: @Mister Jojo, thanks that certainly resolves the `$` to `£` problem but unfortunately the output is missing two backslashes and a `t`.

Comment: @steveOw In string literals, backslashes need to be escaped with another backslash. `"\s" === "s"` and `"\t"` is a tab character.

Comment: @ user4642212 Yes, thanks, I was sort of aware of that.  I need to look at how html is storing my text strings, it looks like it is using double backslahes internally (as reported by the debugger) which would make things straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mister Jojo, I learned that `replaceAll()` is the best way to go for my particular problem.

---

I also learnt a key point: the way a string expression is displayed depends (a) upon the way it is input and (b) upon how it is displayed.

(1) If you type `$$ \sin \theta $$` into a `<div>` in a .html document, or into a live  `textbox` then debugger will show the item as `$$ \\sin \\theta $$` and console.log will display it as `$$ \sin \theta $$`.

(2) AND if you type `str = String.raw #$$ \sin \theta $$#` into a javascript script, (where `#` represents the grave character)  then debugger will show the item as `$$ \\sin \\theta $$` and console.log will display it as `$$ \sin \theta $$`.

(3) BUT if you type `str = "$$ \sin \theta $$"` into a javascript script then debugger will show the item as `$$ \sin \theta $$`and console.log will display it as `$$ sin heta $$`.

---

Finally I learned that regex can be avoided using the  `.split` function e.g:-

```js
//Method 1 enter   $$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$  into a <div> 
//   or type/paste into a live input textbox 
//    debugger shows value as  $$ \\sin \\theta = 0.5 $$ 
// console.log shows value as  $$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$   == GOOD.

//Method 2 define inputStr in a script or console using String.raw 
let inputStr = String.raw `$$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$`;
// debugger    shows value as  $$ \\sin \\theta = 0.5 $$ 
// console.log shows value as  $$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$   == GOOD.

//Method 3 define inputStr in a script or console
//let inputStr = "$$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$"; 
// debugger    shows value as  $$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$      
// console.log shows value as  $$  sin  heta = 0.5 $$    == BAD.

  
let tempArray = inputStr.split("") ;
var numChars = tempArray.length;

//... Replace HOT characters (e.g. "$" "\") by COOL characters (e.g. "£" "@" )

var outVal="";
for (var iii = 0; iii < numChars; iii++ )
{
    var aVal = tempArray[iii];
    if      ( aVal == "$" ) {aVal = "£"}  
      //else if ( aVal == "\" ) {aVal = "@"} ; // --> js error
    else if ( aVal == "\\") {aVal = "@"} ; //... to replace single backslash

    outVal += aVal;             
}
        
//... Test that string can be converted back ...

var checkVal = "";
for (var iii = 0; iii < numChars; iii++ )
{
    var cVal = outVal[iii];
    if      ( cVal == "£") {cVal = "$" } 
    else if ( cVal == "@") {cVal = "\\"} ; 
    checkVal += cVal;           
}
console.log (" input string    =", inputStr);
console.log ("converted outVal =", outVal  );
console.log ("        checkVal =", checkVal);   


// Actual results in console.log using method 2:-

//  input string    = $$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$
// converted outVal = ££ @sin @theta = 0.5 ££
//         checkVal = $$ \sin \theta = 0.5 $$
```